# How to reach a components in Firestore using Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K9NK.jpg)

Hey, I need your help please. I'm coding in Kotlin using Fireatore and all what I need to reach this node's value, could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `uid`, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
rootRef.collection("Fraise").document("itSqrMaXd1PK1M6YWe0Z").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val document = task.result
        if (document.exists()) {
            val uid = document.getString("uid")
            Log.d(TAG, uid);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.exception)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** According to your comment, if you want to get all documents that have set the `uid` property to a particular `uid`, then you should use a query like this:

```
val query = rootRef.collection("Fraise").whereEqualTo("uid", uid);
```